# How to insert a few rows of data into an existing .odt file with bash and libreoffice calc headless?

Tags: bash, libreoffice, spreadsheet

Is there a way in bash to open an existing .odt file in libreoffice calc and insert a few rows of data (in headless mode), basically manipulating an .odt file through bash?

I'm reading some PDF files in bash, searching for specific data in this file, and I'm formatting this data to generate a .csv file, which can be opened in LibreOffice Calc. But I can't format fields in .csv, change font size and so on.

What I want instead of using .csv files is opening an existing .odt spreadsheet file (with formatted and colored cells, margins...) and insert data directly from bash into some cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you save the file as .fods (Flat XML ODF) then the content will be readable XML and thus it should be reasonably easy to edit it with bash.